# Placing a bang before an instance variable - !@my_var

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

The `logged_in?` method in the code doesn't use the `@` sign to reference the `current_user` instance variable, does this mean that the variable is local to the `logged_in?` method or does it still reference the `@current_user` variable? I noticed if I write `!@current_user` instead of `!current_user` the method doesn't work correctly. I am slightly confused how this is working under the hood because would if I had a local variable in `logged_in?` named `current_user` and I did not want it to reference the `@current_user` instance variable above.

```
def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: session[:user_id])
end

def logged_in?
    !current_user.nil?
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a message send with an implicit receiver of `self`. If you look at the code you posted, the method `current_user` is defined directly above `logged_in?`.

Comment: Aaaa..now I understand. It is checking if the returned `@current_user` variable is `nil`. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In `logged_in?` you call not an instance variable but a method `current_user` you defined. which in turn returns result of a `User.find_by(id: session[:user_id])`.

Some extra:
Because you use memoization here: `||=` (<- this thing) the method stores result of database call in your instance variable.

Answer (score 0):

`current_user` is just a getter method of `@current_user` instance variable of the same class, in the `logged_in?` you check if this variable is defined (not `nil`). `!` is a refusaling operator (turns `true` to `false` and vice versa).